# Upgrade or Replace CiviCRM 4.7.31

Tags: wordpress, civicrm.settings.php, version

We are using Wordpress 5.7.  Our current CiviCRM version is 4.7.31.  As of August 2020, CiviCRM event registration stopped working due to the Wordpress update.  Now, we can not seem to process memberships through CiviCRM either.  As of now, I am sending people directly to PayPal, but for membership registration should upgrade, update, or replace our current CiviCRM version as it no longer working compatibly with our Wordpress site

Comment: there isn't actually a question here that can be answered.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can upgrade - but you want to first back up your database! It might be that you need to upgrade in a few steps (backing up between each one) - you can get older CiviCRM releases from sourceforge so you could upgrade to 5.10.0 or something & then on to the next hop

We do actually test that upgrades work from 4.7 in our unit tests but real world sites can throw up gotchas

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking whether to try upgrading or just start with a fresh install. It is definitely possible to upgrade from 4.7.31. You'll want to update php too since you're probably still using php 5 and that won't work with the latest civi.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on WP 5.7, its mandatory to upgrade CiviCRM to 5.28 or more. Also there is a latest Civi security release i.e 5.35.1, so its worth upgrading Civi to 5.35.1.